# How to create customize destination(with my own server name, client, username, ect) using JCo3 on Netweaver?

Tags: jco, netweaver

Since Netweaver ship with its own DestinationDataProvider, we can't register our own customized destination data provider. Does means we have to use the Netweaver's destination manager to define a destination and use it in our application? Is there a way to connect to any SAP server and create our own destination without using the Netweaver's destination manager?

Answer (score 3):

The way this is done in JCO 3 is slightly different. The idea is create  Properties & place from where it can be retrieved (flat file, ldap etc)  and then retrieve the same when you want to connect to a sap server.

// So you First use the following code to create the connection parameters

```
    static String DESTINATION_NAME1 = "ABAP_AS_WITHOUT_POOL";
    static String DESTINATION_NAME2 = "ABAP_AS_WITH_POOL";
    static
    {
        Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "sap.dsc.com");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR,  "76");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "800");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER,   "dsc007");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "passwd");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG,   "en");
        createDestinationDataFile(DESTINATION_NAME1, connectProperties);
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_POOL_CAPACITY, "3");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PEAK_LIMIT,    "10");
        createDestinationDataFile(DESTINATION_NAME2, connectProperties);

    }

     static void createDestinationDataFile(String destinationName, Properties connectProperties)
    {
        File destCfg = new File(destinationName+".jcoDestination");
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destCfg, false);
            connectProperties.store(fos, "for tests only !");
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create the destination files", e);
        }
    }
```

// The following code snippet can then  be used elsewhere to connect to the sap server

```
    static String DESTINATION_NAME1 = "ABAP_AS_WITHOUT_POOL";
    static String DESTINATION_NAME2 = "ABAP_AS_WITH_POOL";

    public static void step1Connect() throws JCoException
   {
        JCoDestination destination =     JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(DESTINATION_NAME1);
        System.out.println("Attributes:");
        System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is from the original SAP Jco 3 document. However, this doesn't work on Netweaver. It only work when using stand alone Jco3 jar lib, and on Netweaver there is a different implementation of Jco3 pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NetWeaver's Destination Service. Either create the RFC destinations via the NetWeaver Admin UI or programmatically via the offered APIs for managing the destination configurations.
Nevertheless, you can also create `JCoCustomDestination` instances based on the `JCoDestination` instances retrieved from the `JCoDestinationManager`.